# VSCODE - How to select python version thought remote ssh?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

How can I execute python 3.9 using remote ssh through vscode?

When I connect to the server, it only run as 2.6

My code:

```
from platform import python_version
  
print("Current Python Version-", python_version())
```

output:

```
[Running] python -u "/root/python/projetos.py"
('Current Python Version-', '2.6.6')
```

Is there any way to select the python version through vscode? I've tried to change at Linux level (using `alternative` command), but don't work.

What I need is vscode to call python3.9 command instead of python command :

```
[root@quickstart ~]# python --version
Python 2.6.6
[root@quickstart ~]# python3.9 --version
Python 3.9.10
[root@quickstart ~]#
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've find out.

Need to install python vscode extension on remote ssh server.

When connected to the SSH Server, in extensions (`Ctrl + shift + x`), look for python and so, install in SSH:

[image]

After install, type `Ctrl + shift + p` and look for `Python: select interpreter.`

[image]

And here will show all python interpreters paths installed on the server.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go shortcut, then simply create a conda environment with Python 3.9 on it. If you do not want to create a separate conda environment, then you can upgrade/add the Python version you want to your server. That means you are brave enough to go the hard way, and then follow the instructions to install it from scratch.

Transfer the compression version of the files to your server:

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.0/Python-3.9.0.tgz
```

Decompress the tar gz file

```
tar xvzf Python-3.4.3.tgz
```

Go to decompressed dir

```
cd Python-3.4.3
```

Install Python there

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/.local
```

Do make install for pip and setuptools for Python packages

```
make
make install
```

All these commands finish up the Python installation. Once this one is all set, then
we will need to add the path to the environment.
Go to the home dir and open .bash_profile or .profile file
cd $home
vi .bash_profile
Add export path statement there

```
export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
```

Then save file and run the bash file

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Installation should be all done. To check it, run

```
python --version
```

Hope it helps.